# List of Seforim that Collect Midrashim on the Parsha

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, torah-study, midrash, pentateuch-chumash

I'm looking for a list of seforim that collect midrashim on the Parsha. In particular, I am looking for a sefer or seforim that can help me see what happens between the lines of the pesukim according to Chazal and the sequence of events. For example, in the beginning of Parshas Vayigash, there is a whole story behind the scenes mentioned in some midrashim. I would love if there was almost like a history book with the sequence of events that includes the pesukim and the "between-the-lines" midrashim.

Comment: The "Let My Nation" series by Yosef Deutsch is very good for this, although not a good answer to the question as it only covers certain maasim in Chumash. If you are happy to accept an online service instead of a sefer, Sefaria is amazing for this. Click on any pasuk and every single Midrash that mentions it pops up in the side bar and you can click it and see them side by side.

Comment: Me'am Loez aka Torah Anthology is a great resource.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possibilities is the collection called "The Midrash Says" by Rabbi Rabbi Moshe Weissman.

The blurb on [Eichlers](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/the-midrash-says-volume-1/2675) writes as follows:

> The narrative of the weekly Torah-portion in the perspective of our Sages. Selected and adapted from the Talmud and Midrash. All the volumes in this popular series will not fail to inspire and stimulate the reader while providing vital information on the Parshah.

"The Midrash Says" can be bought via different resellers:

[Eichlers (volume 1-5)](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/the-midrash-says-volume-1/2675)

[Mekor Judaica (5-volume set or individual volumes)](https://mekorjudaica.com/the-midrash-says.html)

[SeforimCenter](https://seforimcenter.com/The-Midrash-Says-Series__c-p-0-0-109.aspx), including a [peek-view](https://seforimcenter.com/The-Midrash-Says-Series/The-Midrash-Says-on-the-Torah-5-Vol.__p-109-2380.aspx)

[Greenfield Judaica Seforim](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/the-midrash-says---ages-13-to-120-MSAYS.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the [**Otzar Midrashim**](https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim?tab=contents) by Rabbi Yehuda Dovid Eisenstein which describes 200 minor midrashim, and includes the full text of some shorter midrashim, available to buy at all good seforim stores e.g. [here](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/otzar-midrashim-2-volume-set/33064)

You might want to also consider the [**Meam Loez**](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/the-torah-anthology-meam-loez-full-45-volume-set/36559) by [Rabbi Yaakov Culi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Culi) which provides an encyclopedic, well-sourced overview of the parshios, a lot of which is midrash-based.

In a similar vein, I would also recommend the **Torah Sheleima** set by [Rabbi Menachem Kasher](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/kasher-menahem) which is similarly;

> An encyclopedia of the Gemara and Midrash, in which all relevant material in the oral law, both published and in manuscript, is collected according to the Scriptural verse to which it applies together with notes, expositions, and supplements. Thirty-three volumes, covering Genesis–Leviticus 24:23 had been published by 1981 (the first volume appeared in 1927)

The multiple volumes are fully available on Hebrewbooks